# Sonarqube, getting Zero Code Coverage for scala project

Tags: scala, sonarqube, code-coverage

I am scanning the scala multi-module project. I am getting the module reports as:

```
[INFO] Statement coverage.: 36.07%
[INFO] Branch coverage....: 6.25%
[INFO] Coverage reports completed.
[DEBUG] Mojo execution time: 2516 ms
```

But still getting

```
[DEBUG] 08:48:16.724 Sensors : Zero Coverage Sensor
[INFO] 08:48:16.725 Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor
[INFO] 08:48:16.756 Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor (done) | time=31ms
```

The coverage report on sonar dashboard is 0%

The jacoco.exec and jacoco.xml reports are also getting generated.

Below is section from pom:

```
<!-- Sonar -->
        <sonar.version>3.7.0.1746</sonar.version>
        <jacoco.version>0.7.9</jacoco.version>
        <sonar.projectName>abc</sonar.projectName>
        <sonar.projectDescription>abc:xyz</sonar.projectDescription>
        <sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin>
        <sonar.jacoco.reportPaths>jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPaths>
        <sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
        <sonar.language>scala</sonar.language>
        <sonar.sources>src/main/scala</sonar.sources>
        <sonar.binaries>target/classes</sonar.binaries>
        <sonar.inclusions>**/*.scala</sonar.inclusions>
        <sonar.exclusions>src/test/**</sonar.exclusions>
        <scoverage.plugin.version>1.4.1</scoverage.plugin.version>
        <sonar.java.coveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.java.coveragePlugin>
        <sonar.scala.coveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.scala.coveragePlugin>
        <sonar.scala.coverage.reportPath>target/scoverage.xml</sonar.scala.coverage.reportPath>
        <sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths>${project.build.directory}/jacoco.xml</sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths>
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
        <!-- Sonar -->
.
.
.
<configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>jacoco.exec</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>

.
.
.
<!-- Sonar -->
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>/src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>/src/test/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-resource-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includeEmptyDirs>true</includeEmptyDirs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resource</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>jacoco.exec</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-test-resource</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>testResources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.testOutputDirectory}</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.16</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>-XX:-UseSplitVerifier -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Xms256m
                        -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
                    </argLine>
                    <redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-release-plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <destFile>${sonar.jacoco.reportPath}</destFile>
                    <append>true</append>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>post-unit-test</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report-aggregate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <dataFile>jacoco.exec</dataFile>
                            <outputEncoding>UTF-8</outputEncoding>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                            <systemPropertyVariables>
                  <jacoco-agent.destfile>jacoco.exec</jacoco-agent.destfile>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

What am I missing? I am struggling to get the code coverage on sonar dashboard. Please help..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the same case, but we had a similar issue using `Scoverage` and the problem was related to the path where the reports were generated, it seems that `SonarCloud` was looking at a different path. We solved it by replacing paths like this:

```bash
sed -i -e 's/\/home\/github\/_work\/my-scala-project\/my-scala-project\/src/\/github\/workspace\/src/g' target/scala-2.13/scoverage-report/scoverage.xml
```

In our case the paths correspond to a GitHub Action.